# AJV JSON schema validation - How to validate object containing object for uniqueness using ajv json schema validator

Tags: angular, typescript, jsonschema, ajv

I have the example like below,

```
"obj2": 
{
    {
      "prop1": "baz", "prop2": 999
     },
    {
      "prop1": "qux", "prop2": 555
     }
 }
```

i.e. object containing objects, now in this i need '**prop1**' field to have unique values using ajv JSON schema validator

***Note**:* I know this is possible when it is array of object, but i don't think there is any solution for the same case when object containing objects.

There seems no solution for this!

Comment: Are you sure that's the right structure? Have you tried to access any key/value of those objects?

Comment: Unfortunately, there's no solution for this using JSON Schema.

Comment: @MishaMashina, yes this how the structure is, and i want to have the value's to be unique for "prop1" fields

Comment: @JasonDesrosiers, really! because they have this kind of unique value solution for array of objects!,. Then why not for object containing objects?